# Android / AppWidget - how to load different content to StackView by clicking on different buttons?

Tags: android, android-widget, onclicklistener, stackview

Assume that I have a app-widget which contains an stack-view and four buttons.

I want to load different data into stack-view by clicking on each of those four buttons.

**Things I know:**

I know how to populate an stack view in app-widget by fetching data from a URL.

and I know how to call an intent in onUpdate to call RemoteViewsService and fill stack-view:

```
Intent intentNews = new Intent(context, StackWidgetService.class);
intentNews.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
intentNews.setData(Uri.parse(intentNews.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.svShowContentOfApp, intentNews);
```

**What I want to do:**

how to implement onClick for each of my buttons to call different RemoteViewsService and load different content into my stack-view.

**Edit:**

I made some advance:

I figure it out that how to click on a button using this piece of code:

```
Intent intentClick = new Intent(context, getClass());
intentClick.setAction(ACTION);
PendingIntent PIClick = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentClick, 0);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView, PIClick);
```

and in onReceive I can call RemoteViewsService like this:

```
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.total_app_widget);

    if (ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        //>>> for loading a data into stack-view
        Intent intentNews = new Intent(context, StackWidgetServiceNews.class);
        intentNews.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIdNews);
        intentNews.setData(Uri.parse(intentNews.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        views.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIdNews, R.id.svShowContentOfApp, intentNews);
        // -------------------------------------- loading a data into stack-view

        ComponentName widget = new ComponentName(context, TotalAppWidget.class);
        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(widget, views);

    } 
}
```

when I click on button, stackView disappears and empty-view shows instead.
according to Logs everything is OK but stack-view never displays again. looks like remoteView doesn't became update?